# Парсинг столбца и разворот по его значениям

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица конфет

```
Id    name      parameter
1   Конфета1    синяя, вкусная, блестящая
2   Конфета2    красивая, сладкая, синяя, вкусная
```

Есть справочник параметров

```
Id name
1  синяя
2  вкусная
3  блестящая
4  красивая
5  сладкая
6  красная
```

Мне нужно распарсить поле parameter    и развернуть его в строку и получить id

```
Id    name   parameterId
1   Конфета1    1
2   Конфета1    2
3   Конфета1    3
4   Конфета2    4
5   Конфета2    5
6   Конфета2    1
7   Конфета2    3
```

Comment: У вас неправильная структура таблицы. Должна быть вторая таблица где будет лежать строго по одному параметру к одному id конфеты. Тогда работать с помощью SQL с ней будет удобно (потому как SQL предназначен для работы с нормализованными данными https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). А в том виде как сейчас вам надо делать join по like для поиска подстроки, после чего собирать id обратно в строку group_concat

Comment: Какая у вас база данных? MS SQL Server, MySQL, и т.п.

Comment: MS SQL Server. Я Вас понимаю, согласна что это неправильно, но задача именно такая

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin, Каким-то образом этот пост стал невидимым. Вы не могли бы проверить?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Пожалуйста, не обращайте внимания на мой комментарий. Кто-то удалил тег **sql** из этого поста, поэтому моя ссылка перестала его показывать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, убрал метку я. согласно её краткому описанию, она никак не подходит к данному вопросу.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, 

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky посмотрите мой комментарий к ответу:)

Answer (score 2):

Вот как это сделать в MS SQL Server.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @конфет TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [name] NVARCHAR(20), parameterList NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @конфет (name, parameterList)
VALUES
(N'Конфета1', N'синяя, вкусная, блестящая'),
(N'Конфета2', N'красивая, сладкая, синяя, вкусная');

DECLARE @parameter TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [name] NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @parameter ([name]) VALUES
(N'синяя'),
(N'вкусная'),
(N'блестящая'),
(N'красивая'),
(N'сладкая'),
(N'красная');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , CAST('<root><r>' + 
              REPLACE(parameterList, @separator, '</r><r>') + 
            '</r></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @конфет
)
SELECT rs.ID, rs.[name], p.ID
    , c.value('(./text())[1] cast as xs:token?', 'NVARCHAR(20)') AS parameter
FROM rs 
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root/r') AS t(c)
    INNER JOIN @parameter AS p
        ON c.value('(./text())[1] cast as xs:token?', 'NVARCHAR(20)') = p.[name];
```

> Вывод

```
+----+----------+----+-----------+
| ID |   name   | ID | parameter |
+----+----------+----+-----------+
|  1 | Конфета1 |  1 | синяя     |
|  1 | Конфета1 |  2 | вкусная   |
|  1 | Конфета1 |  3 | блестящая |
|  2 | Конфета2 |  4 | красивая  |
|  2 | Конфета2 |  5 | сладкая   |
|  2 | Конфета2 |  1 | синяя     |
|  2 | Конфета2 |  2 | вкусная   |
+----+----------+----+-----------+
```

> MS SQL Server 2016 и более поздние версии, STRING_SPLIT()

```
-- Method #2
-- by Novitskiy Denis
 SELECT * 
 FROM @конфет
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(parameterList, @separator)
    INNER JOIN @parameter AS p ON LTRIM(value) = p.[name];
```

> MS SQL Server 2016 и более поздние версии, Json

```
-- Method #3
SELECT * 
FROM @конфет
    CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM([value])) AS [word]
          FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(parameterList, @separator, '","') + '"]')
        ) AS j
INNER JOIN @parameter AS p ON j.[word] = p.[name];
```

Comment: stranges, Если предлагаемое решение работает для вас, не забудьте указать, что это ответ.

Comment: добавьте вариант со string_split, вдруг версия сервера позволяет:) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ae6739e6867b43970ed97ae147bbbf2

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, Спасибо.